# Differentiable transition function between functions

Tags: functions

Imagine you have a function `y=f(x)` made of two functions that share a given point:

```
f(x) = h(x) for x between [0,0.05]
f(x) = g(x) for x between [0.05,0.15]

h(x) = 4*x
g(x) = 2*x + 2*0.05
```

How to build a function `w(x)` which makes `f(x)` differentiable in all range, i.e.:

Given a certain range of `x` values where `w(x)` is defined, e.g. `[0.04,0.06]` one has:

```
dw/dx|x=0.04 = dh/dx|x=0.04 
dw/dx|x=0.06 = dg/dx|x=0.06
and dw is differentiable between [0.04,0.06].
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

If you only want *continuous*, linear interpolation helps. In your specific case
$$ w(x)=\begin{cases}h(x)&\text{if }x\le 0.04\\
\frac{(x-0.04)g(0.06)+(0.06-x)h(0.04)}{0.02}&\text{if } 0.04< x< 0.06\\
g(x)&\text{if }x\ge 0.06\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 0):

I've found `sigmoid functions`:

```
w(x) = 1/(1+exp(-(x - x0)/alfa))
```

Then I could do:

```
f(x)= (1-w(x))*h(x) + w(x)*g(x)
```

but this seem to work great only when the functions are discontinuous at the interface point. In  my case the two functions share a common point, they are continuous, but f(x) is not differentiable at the shared point

Comment: I solved it by determining the coefs of a third order polynomial....